# Can't go on clicking on the next page button while scraping certain fields from a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I've created a script using python in association with ***[pyppeteer](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/)*** to keep clicking on the next page button until there is no more. The script while clicking on the next page button throws this error `pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000 ms exceeded.` pointing at this line `await page.waitForNavigation()`. It can parse `name` and `item_type` from the landing page of that site, though. I know I can issue post http requests with appropriate payload to get data from there but my intention is to make use of `pyppeteer` and keep clicking on the next page button while parsing the required fields.

> [website address](https://www.e-ports.com/ships)

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

link = "https://www.e-ports.com/ships"

async def get_content():
    wb = await launch(headless=True)
    [page] = await wb.pages()
    await page.goto(link)

    while True:
        await page.waitForSelector(".common_card", {'visible':True})

        elements = await page.querySelectorAll('.common_card')
        for element in elements:
            name = await element.querySelectorEval('span.title > a','e => e.innerText')
            item_type = await element.querySelectorEval('.bottom > span','e => e.innerText')
            print(name.strip(),item_type.strip())

        try:
            await page.click("button.btn-next")
            await page.waitForNavigation()
        except Exception: break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(get_content())
```

Btw, If I manually click on the next page button for the first time, It accomplishes the rest successfully.

Comment: According to the author, [this](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/issues/58#issuecomment-377903899) is the right approach `await asyncio.wait([page.click(...), page.waitForNavigation()])`. However, it could not solve the issue either. The script starts clicking on the next page button only when I click on the button manually for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the valid syntax in Pypeteer, but common syntax of `waitForNavigation` maybe this one.

```
await Promise.all([
   page.waitForNavigation(),
   page.click("button.btn-next")
])
```

With the iterator inside the array promised, all of the methods will resolved when become true or finished desired action.

Comment: I believe it's `await asyncio.gather(func1, func2)`